# MSB3073 UE4 exited with code 6 - how do I fix this?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, unreal-engine4

Ok, so I'm taking a udemy course on UE4 and when compiling I have a issue where I'm presented with my file location and told it exited with code 6. There are also a lot of errors saying that say it can't read my macros - how do I fix this? I'm relatively new to this so try to make it as simple as possible when answering. Thank you.

Comment: Did you follow [this guidance](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Development/VisualStudioSetup/index.html) to install UE4? Also, what is your project type and vs version? Besides, please share with us your detailed error log so that we can help you troubleshoot your issue quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise paying close attention to syntax and UPROPERTY (what is in here).

For example, I had this situation:

```
    struct FGridCoord
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, EditAnywhere, Category = "Grids")
    int Col = 0;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, EditAnywhere, Category = "Grids")
    int Row = 0;

    /** Default constructor (no initialization). */
    FORCEINLINE FGridCoord() {}    <<<------ This was giving same error ---->>> FORCEINLINE FGridCoord();
```

And other one I had:

```
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category = "Grids", meta = (AllowPrivateAcsess = "true")) <<<---- It had BlueprintReadOny and was giving an error
USceneComponent* RootComp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact error this question lists (also taking a Udemy course on Unreal LOL), syntax all looked fine (this project/environment worked fine the last time I used it, some months ago) and hadn't changed, so I decided to clean the solution and rebuild.

This time I got a slightly different error, and it mentioned needing Windows SDK installed.

[image: VS Error]

A quick Google of that seems to show that yeah, that's what's needed. Visual Studio Installer showed under C++ Game Development that none of the Windows SDK options were checked/installed. Since I'm running Windows 10 I checked the most recent/highest version of W10SDK and installed that.

After that I tried loading my project from the Epic Games Launcher, just like I did before starting my Udemy course 30 minutes prior. Now that said it was missing a module and that it needed to be rebuilt. Clicked "OK." The project rebuild failed.

I saw Unreal Engine could be updated from 4.27.1 (which I created my project in and which had been working without issue some months ago, like I said) to 4.27.2. Downloaded the 4GB update, still got the "missing module, rebuild" error but after clicking "OK" that time it built and UE 4 opened the project. VS2022 now builds the solution, and I can play the project within UE 4.

I have no fricking clue what just happened here, cause this all worked last time I worked on it and I changed nothing in the meantime, but it all works now.

So for others that get this, maybe:

1. Try cleaning your solution and see if you perhaps need to install Windows SDK
2. Maybe upgrade your UE 4 a minor version, if it's available

Head asplodes ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

```
Error   MSB3073 The command ""C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.3\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat" MyProject Win64 Development -Project="C:\MyProject\MyProject.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6. MyProject C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets  44
```

Is surfaced in Visual Studio (VS) when you tell VS to build while the Unreal Engine (UE) editor is still open.

As a rule, any time you touch C++ in UE, close the editor.